# Different image sizes in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress

I'm trying to get different image sizes on my wordpress website. For instance, I want the image size "thumbnail" to be displayed in category post list. While image size "Medium" should be displayed on actual post page. Right now, only thumbnail size images get displayed both on post list and on individual post. I realize I need to make some changes in my theme, but exactly what are those?

Comment: If you could post the theme, that would help us a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the template file of your theme that handles the "post page" as you call it- most likely "single.php" (for single posts) and "page.php" (for pages)-unless the theme author has added custom templates- and find where the thumbnail image is being referenced. You should be able to reference the "medium" version of your uploaded image there instead. However, the theme author may be using an automatic thumbnail script to resize your image (such as TimThumb) and not the Wordpress-generated thumbnails as you might be thinking. If this is the case, you will have to swap out the thumbnailing code on the image tag in 'single.php' for a reference to the "medium" image...

Perhaps if you provided the example code in your single.php file where the thumbnailed image is called would help us give you a more specific answer on how you need to changes things.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out myself. The theme author was using gallery_shortcode function. I passed a different custom global for each of single.php, page.php, index.php etc. It works now.